# Use of "life's" in a sentence

Tags: grammar

Please review sentence below and advise if the use of "life's" is correct.

> Unlocking life's potential for young adults.

Comment: This is a legit question about the genitive...

Comment: @Nihilist_Frost Is it wrong to say potential(s) of life ?

Comment: English allows both genitives.  Saying "Life's potential" and "The potential of life" is roughly the same.  The second way is more formal.

Comment: I saw  three expressions *life potential *, *life's potential *, *the potential of life* .

Answer (score 2):

Sounds correct to me (native American English speaker).  The English genitive is fairly flexible, and this would be equally well understood as

> Unlocking the potential of life for young adults.

but again, this is fine as written.